# Is there a process faster than masking frame by frame for cutting an animated character from a background?

Tags: compositing

The following video is made from a number of different Anime videos, masked and composed in to a single video. I am wondering if the person who made this masked the videos frame by frame or is there a faster way in achieving this?

I am just asking for guidelines or another way of cutting the characters from a background, in an Anime which is made of a limited number colors.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPv6c3xGwzw&spfreload=1

Here is an example of a replaced character in the video:

[image]

Comment: The technique is called rotoscoping.  You can search for many ways to speed up or automate rotoscoping.  But in general it is a labor-intensive process.

Comment: After effects and other compositing packages have tools which make this easier (roto-brush in AE for one example). They work a bit like the magic wand in Potatoshop. They're not perfect, but they would probably work fairly well on Anime with its flat colours and hard edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also checkout some of the various keying techniques. I've been able to color key things pretty well in After Effects or Nuke - for After Effects you can either use "Change to Color" to create a matte or "Linear Color Key". Either way you're going to need to split up the video into a bunch of layers - each one keying in (or out) a specific color. The end result you're going for is a black-and-white matte which you can use to cut out the footage. Often times it requires a combination of all kinds of techniques - keying some colors, luminance based keying (which can be done with "extract" in After Effects), luminance based keying on specific channels (also "extract") and a bit of hand-made roto.

If you need a more in depth explanation let me know.

Comment: What do I do if it also keys out some parts of the character ?

Comment: That's where the roto part comes in ;)  It's not a perfect technique unfortunately. If you give me a still frame I can take a look at it and try to give you some pointers.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, I think rotoscoping is more than enough it's already a lot of help for me since I have always been masking.